# Object not constructed and related typeid information

Tags: c++, constructor, rtti, default-constructor, typeid

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class Base { 
public: 
    ~Base() { 
        static int count = 0; 
        cout << "...calling destructor " << ++count << endl;
    }
};

#include <typeinfo> 

int main () { 

    Base b0; 
    Base b1 = Base(); 
    Base b2();

    cout << typeid(b1).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(b2).name() << " : " << b2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> ```
> 4Base
> F4BasevE : 1
> ...calling destructor 1
> ...calling destructor 2
> ```

In the above code, I am expecting to create three objects of type `Base` which has no user-defined constructors.

As is obvious in the output, the destructor is invoked only twice. Inspecting object `b2` using `typeid`, emits the strange `F4BasevE` string (as opposed to `4Base`).

Questions:

1. What does `F4BasevE` mean?
2. `1` appear when trying to print `b2` - what does that mean?
3. What constructor do I have to define in the class to be able to
   create object `b2` the way it is defined?

Comment: `Base b2();` is a function declaration. See [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).

Comment: What's the explanation for the `1` output (line 2)?

Comment: I believe it may be printing the address of the function `b2`. I get 000000013FBD1046 in Visual Studio 2015, instead of 1.